# Twig json_encode with multiple options

Tags: php, symfony, twig

[From the TWIG documentaion about `json_encode()` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html) they say:

> **json_encode**
>
> The json_encode filter returns the JSON representation of a value:
>
> ```
> {{ data|json_encode() }}
> ```
>
> Internally, Twig uses the PHP [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) function.
>
> Arguments
>
> options: A bitmask of json_encode options
>
> ```
> ({{data|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }})
> ```

What I'm trying to do is to add multiple of those options.

I want the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` and `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`

I have tried

```
{{ array|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES')) }}
{{ array|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES')) }}
{{ array|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT', 'JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES')) }}
```

But none of them work. How can I combine two options for TWIGs `json_encode()` filter?

[TwigFiddle here](http://twigfiddle.com/t9s11p)

```
{% set array = {'xxx': "one", 'yyy': "two", 'path': "/hello/world" } %}

{% autoescape false %}
    {{ array|json_encode() }}
    {{ array|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}
    {{ array|json_encode(constant('JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES')) }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Desired output should be

```
{
    "xxx": "one",
    "yyy": "two",
    "path": "/hello/world"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that you need `b-or` for a bitwise or operation ([docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#logic)) in twig.

So something like this should work:

```
{{ array|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT') b-or constant('JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES')) }}
```